# Regex for Wordpress redirection plugin

Tags: regex, redirect

I'm using this redirection plugin https://redirection.me and I'd like to redirect traffic if a query parameter is not present:

```
/relative-location/?must-be-there=value&other1=value&other2=value
```

If `must-be-there` is not there or has no value, I'd like to redirect - but I do not know how to write the regular expression to make that work. I started with

```
^((?!must[-]be[-]there).)*$
```

but I don't know where to go next to create the full url and have it work with the plugin.

Comment: You've asked for a regex to match something, which is one question. What do you mean by "create the full url", which seems like a separate question?

Comment: Sorry. I was unclear. The path and query sting might have other elements, or not, but if someone tries to access this known path /home-contact-part-two/ without the lead-score-a=5 or some value then they get redirected. the target URL gets handled by the plugin. I need the regex that says if someone goes to /home-contact-part-two/ with the lead-score-a= some value part then they redirect. Example: 

/home-contact-part-two/?utm_source=test-source&utm_medium=test-medium&lead-score-a=5&lname=Smith

... would allow you to view the page.

Comment: but all the examples below would redirect

/home-contact-part-two/?utm_source=test-source&utm_medium=test-medium&lname=Smith
/home-contact-part-two/
/home-contact-part-two/?lead-score-a=&fname=John
/home-contact-part-two/?lead-score-a=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match when the path starts with `/relative-location/`, but query parameter `must-be-there` either has with no value or is missing:

```
^/relative-location/(?!.*(\?|&)must-be-there=[^&]).*$
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/ADbfONZtYDI46C).

Comment: Sorry. I was unclear. The path and query sting might have other elements, or not, but if someone tries to access this known path /home-contact-part-two/ without the lead-score-a=5 or some value then they get redirected. the target URL gets handled by the plugin. I need the regex that says if someone goes to /home-contact-part-two/ with the lead-score-a= some value part then they redirect. Example: 

/home-contact-part-two/?utm_source=test-source&utm_medium=test-medium&lead-score-a=5&lname=Smith

... would allow you to view the page.

Comment: but all the examples below would redirect

/home-contact-part-two/?utm_source=test-source&utm_medium=test-medium&lname=Smith
/home-contact-part-two/
/home-contact-part-two/?lead-score-a=&fname=John
/home-contact-part-two/?lead-score-a=

Comment: @user2141579 did you look at the sample inputs in the linked demo? I created all edge cases I could think of, and AFAICT this regex will do what you want. If you disagree, please describe exactly why it doesn’t work.

Comment: I did. I need to include the known path /home-contact-part-two/ before the part that matches any query string does not include lead-score-a=value 

it looks like your regex matches both lead-score-a= and lead-score-a=value. but this needs to match does not equal 'lead-score-a=value.'

Comment: .... so if the lead-score-a field is empty or the its not there then I can redirect them. thanks for your help with this.

Comment: I don't know how to say this any other way, but my regex matches `must-be-there=` and when `must-be-there` is not there at all. Please examine the live demo closely and identify to me which of the 5 examples match incorrectly. Also, your recent comments refer to `home-contact-part-two` and `lead-score-a` - could you please stay with the terms used in your question so we are both on the same page.

Comment: This is the redirect plugin I'm working with https://redirection.me/ (from the original post) and here is the UI https://bigidearesults.com/files/redirect-ui.png which is why the /relative-location/ part needs to be explicit (i.e., /home-contact-part-two/). And the redirect needs to happen if must-be-there is not equal to must-be-there=value or must-be-there is not in the query string. I should have included the UI image in the original post. Thanks.

Comment: @user2141579 Having now mentioned that the regex should only match the specific path, I have restricted matches to only match when the path starts with `/relative-location/` and `must-be-there` was either sent with no value or is missing.

Comment: PERFECT! It works exactly as I'd hoped. Fantastic. Thank you for your help.